# Usar arquivos JSON com JavaScript na web

Tags: javascript

eu tenho um enorme array com inúmeros objetos, queria saber se posso exportalo para o meu arquivo JS principal?

já fiz:

module.exports = nomeDoArray

mas quando abro no navegador aparece a mensagem de error: 'require is not defined'

Comment: Lucas, por acaso você está executando o seu código com `node.js` ?

Comment: Você usa o module.exports em outra solicitação? Posta o código que facilita entender

Comment: Não estou executando com nodeJS, queria saber se posso exportar um array de um outro arquivo JS só que executando no navegador

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando Node apenas use require no arquivo json

```js
const array = require('path./file.json');
```

no navegador vc pode usar o `fetch` ou o ajax para fazer a request do arquivo no servidor:

```js
const array = await fetch('path/file.json').then(r => r.json());
```

Answer (score -3):

Cara pelo o que entendi se está com um arquivo.html e dentro dele se tem um script.js e se quer que o script consiga acessar um arquivo com dados externo, certo?

Se for isso se vai ter que colocar o arquivo no teu código html, mas talvez vele apena avaliar uma mudança (atualização no teu código) que se for o que eu entendi tá bem arcaico